# Как получить sql-запрос?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

делаю запрос:

```
mysql.query("INSERT INTO `test` (`val`, `val2`) VALUES ?", [[3, 3],[5,5]], function(err, result) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
});
```

получаю ошибку:

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '3, 3' at line 1

не пойму в чем ошибка

как можно увидеть запрос, который в итоге отсылается в mysql?

`UPDATE`
пример из документации:

```
  var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES ?";
  var values = [
    ['John', 'Highway 71'],
    ['Peter', 'Lowstreet 4'],
    ['Amy', 'Apple st 652'],
    ['Hannah', 'Mountain 21'],
    ['Michael', 'Valley 345'],
    ['Sandy', 'Ocean blvd 2'],
    ['Betty', 'Green Grass 1'],
    ['Richard', 'Sky st 331'],
    ['Susan', 'One way 98'],
    ['Vicky', 'Yellow Garden 2'],
    ['Ben', 'Park Lane 38'],
    ['William', 'Central st 954'],
    ['Chuck', 'Main Road 989'],
    ['Viola', 'Sideway 1633']
  ];
  con.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
  });
```

https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: Синтаксис запроса должен быть `... values(?,?),(?,?)` примет ли он потом многомерный массив как параметры я не знаю. проверяйте. И да, текст запроса придется построить самому ориентируясь на длину массива

Comment: так работает: `INSERT INTO test (val, val2) VALUES (3, 3),(5,5)`, но вот пример передачи массива https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_insert.asp, у меня не работает

Comment: хм, походу он первый параметр таки подставил целиком, немного неожиданно, ну да ладно, попробуйте поставить скобки ` ... values (?)`

Comment: заработало, спасибо

Comment: поторопился, добавилась только первая строчка

Comment: ну да, я этого боялся. Не знаю почему в той статье так написано. Ни в одном языке так не работает. прочитав ее я подумал что node исключение. правда он умудряется подставить два значения на 1 `?` тогда должно выходить `values (?),(?)` для двух строк

Comment: в документации сказано: Nested arrays are turned into grouped lists (for bulk inserts), e.g. [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']] turns into ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd') https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values